# edit contents of elements based on custom markers (like ** bold **)

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname, textstyle

I was wondering if it was possible to change text-styles if there is a marker surrounding the text (like in discord messages) 
My approach would be to first get all the elements of the page that (usually) contain text

```js
const getTagName = (x) => document.getElementByTagName(x);
let p = getTagName("p");
let h1 = getTagName("h1");
let h2 = getTagName("h2");
let h3 = getTagName("h3");
let h4 = getTagName("h4");
let h5 = getTagName("h5");
let h6 = getTagName("h6");
//there are probbably much more text-containing-elements, but for here i dont really care
```

Then i would look through them to find for example "**" ... "**" and put the contents in  a `<span style="font-weight: 900">\</span>` element.
And here is my problem: I don´t see a 'usual' way to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "usual"? There's two approaches: do it manually (get text, compare text against whatever syntax you're using, update container's styles/CSS), or use a Markdown processor (if there's one that meets your syntax requirements).

Comment: The question I'd ask *first*, though, is *why*? What problem are you trying to solve? E.g., why couldn't this be done by applying appropriate CSS in the first place? Why is the original data "pre-formatted" with "Markdown"?

Comment: You can use the `innerHTML` property of an element to retrieve the content as a string and replace the custom markers plus enclosed text with what you want. However, that simple approach need to be augmented in the case of nesting. Beware: this approach is *not recommended* (you would operate on structured content without proper regard to the structure).

Comment: the problem is i dont know how to loop over the elements, I know though that document.getElementsByTagName gives back a list of the elements, so do I just have to `for (pTag in p){}` ?

Comment: Use `let elements = document.getElementsByTagName(<whatever>); for (let item of elements) { <code_applied_to_each_item_in_turn>; }`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) are the docs you need for more info.

Comment: thank you, if you write an answer i can tick it so the question doesn´t appear anymore for the others